# WebRTC with python

Tags: python, opencv, twisted, webrtc

I would like to make a streaming server with python/twisted, which receives a WebRTC video stream and then applys some OpenCV algorithms to it.

However I cannot find a python module for WebRTC. How can I send and receive a WebRTC video stream with python/twisted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is take screen shots continuously and push them to a websocket and allow your twisted server to take a gander at each one as it comes in.

I have modified some common recorders and my version takes Jpeg images and pushes them over a websocket. Feel free to use and modify how you want so that it fits your needs. [Source code here](https://github.com/Computician/WebSocketWebRTCRecorders/blob/master/Scripts/WSVideoRecorder.js). The example I use is pushing down to a libwebsocket server built in C but the same javascript could be used to send to any websocket server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So there is currently no way to directly receive the webrtc vp8 video stream in python and decode it?

Comment: You MAY be able to work with http://lynckia.com/licode/ as they have a native C++ WebRTC MCU that you could forward streams to your server over UDP.

Comment: I would use `MediaRecorder` instead of taking screenshots, since it is more efficient in terms of bandwith since the stream is encoded properly, whereas the screenshot solution send each image individually.

Answer (score 5):

I have started putting together the basic blocks needed to create a Python WebRTC endpoint.

One is an asyncio-based Interactive Connectivity Establishment module:

https://github.com/jlaine/aioice

Another one is a Python binding for libsrtp:

https://github.com/jlaine/pylibsrtp

We also need SRTP keying support in the OpenSSL bindings:

https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/pull/4099

On top of this, we can then build an asyncio-based WebRTC implementation:

https://github.com/jlaine/aiortc

I have been able to get both Chrome and Firefox to establish an audio and video stream to a Python-based server.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue and ended up creating a server that launches a headless chrome instance from which I can access the WebRTC streams, record chunks with a MediaRecorder and finally forward those chunks on via a WebSocket.

I'd love a python based solution so I wouldn't need the intermediary server launching headless chrome instances but haven't been able to find one.

I've been using Node.js and [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) but one could launch the browser instances from your python server and then send the decoded data back via plain old sockets or whatever else tickles your fancy.

Comment: That's insanely cumbersome!